# How to merge again after discarding something in previous merge?

Tags: git, merge

In the past I had `master` branch and `dev`, that was ~15 commits ahead of master. I needed to merge `dev` into `master`, but discard some feature. It was done successfully.

Now some time passed by, I made some new commits to `dev`, and boss said that we should publish feature, that was discarded in the previous merge. So... I'm doing new merge `dev` into `master`, but... but git thinks that everything is fine, it doesn't offer to merge discarded changes again. Now `git merge` says that it's already up to date, but files are different, I see it!

So what should I do to fix this? And what should I have done in the past to make correct merge?

Comment: Did you save discarded changes from `dev` in stash or in another branch?

Comment: Did you actually merge `dev` into `master` a second time?

Comment: @Hamsternik discarded changes now only live in `dev` branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hmm, a second time I merged `dev` into `master` as usual (just fast forward some new commits), but then I realised that old discarded feature is completely gone in `master` and now forever lives in `dev`

Comment: This makes no sense.  How could the feature "live" in `dev` if it weren't merged into `master` at the time you merged it?

Comment: as I understand, you have some commits, which didn't merge in the past. So, you should checkout to necessary commit (by hash), then create a new branch with it, and merge this new branch with the `master`.

Comment: As I understand you merge and then revert merge? In this case you should revert this revert and try merge again ( if dev contains new changes)